# Pandas Dataframe TypeError: translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dataframe

I am trying to delete punctuation and numbers to my pandas dataframe. here is my sample of code :

```
import re
import string
df.text = df.text.apply(lambda x: x.lower())
df.text = df.text.apply(lambda x: x.translate(None, string.punctuation))
```

and it gives me error :

> TypeError: translate() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

I have tried to remove None in translate so it becomes:

```
 df.text = df.text.apply(lambda x: x.translate(string.punctuation))
```

It gave me no errors, but this code didn't remove the punctuation as I wanted. I am using python 2.7. Can you help me ? Thank you in advance

Comment: Where's your regular expression?

Comment: @Tomothy32, sorry, I have just edited my question.

Comment: Do you want to remove your punctuation?

Comment: Are you sure you're using python 2.7?

Comment: @MohitMotwani yes, I want to remove the punctuation in my column. I am actually using jupyter notebook with python 2

Comment: @venikputri Exactly which version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

You can use pandas' built-in [`Series.str.translate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.translate.html):

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ['f!!o..o!', 'b""a??r', 'b?.?a!.!z']})

In [3]: df
Out[3]:
        text
0   f!!o..o!
1    b""a??r
2  b?.?a!.!z

In [4]: import string

In [5]: df.text = df.text.str.translate(None, string.punctuation)

In [6]: df
  text
0  foo
1  bar
2  baz
```

Comment: Thankyou for the answer. When I tried to follow your given example, everything in 'text' column became NaN.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for python 2:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ['f!!o..o!', 'b""a??r', 'b?.?a!.!z']})
      text
0   f!!o..o!
1    b""a??r
2  b?.?a!.!z

import string
table = string.maketrans("","")
df.text = df.text.apply(lambda x: x.translate(table, string.punctuation))

df
   text
0  foo
1  bar
2  baz
```

The make_trans function makes the translation table which is like a dictionary(translate a key to a value)